# Adding Objects From Business Layer

Tags: business-objects

I have created one report in BusinessObjects and saved it inside a folder that is located in "Public Folders". 
I opened a report from the "Public Folder" inside the launch pad and decided that I would like to add few new objects to the report (I would like to add objects from Business Layer).
However, I have noticed that when I open a report, the button "Data" is not available anymore beside the buttons "View" and "Design".
My question is - when I open a pre-created report, is it possible to add additional objects to it afterwards. If yes, where do I do that?

Thanks!
A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's important to note, and this confuses most users, is that there are actually several Web Intelligence clients in BI 4:

- HTML
- Rich Internet Application (RIA): this is actually a Java applet
- Rich Client (WRC): a stand-alone client application that requires a local installation

If you haven't made any changes to the BI Launch pad preferences, and if you have authorisations to all Webi interfaces, depending on the action you're performing, a different Webi client will be used:

- RIA:

  - Starting the Webi application using the icon in the BI Launch pad home tab or the *Applicatons* menu at the top.
  - Right-clicking an existing document and selecting *Modify* from the context menu.
- HTML

  - Double-clicking an existing document (either opens the document itself or the last successful instance)
  - Right-clicking an existing document and selecting *View* from the context menu (or *View latest instance*).

The *Data* tab is only available in the Java (RIA) client, not the HTML client. There are some other differences in functionality as well, but most things you can do with both, with the advantage of the HTML client that it doesn't have the dependency on the Java JRE client.

Here's a good comparison of the HTML and RIA clients: [Comparison of Web Intelligence Java Report Panel and HTML Editor](http://www.businessobjectstips.com/tips/web-intelligence/comparison-web-intelligence-java-report-panel-html-editor/) (Only part one for now, other parts to come).

Configuring BI Launch pad in order to use a different client is described in the tutorial [Set up preferences for the Web Intelligence Rich Client interface](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-21125).

But that wasn't actually your question. You don't need the data tab, you need to open the query panel and modify the data provider. You can do that from any client when you're using a data provider based on a universe (which you are, as you're referring to a Business Layer). You can review how to do this in the tutorial [Edit a query](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-21122).

Comment: Thanks Kristof - I have found the solution - double-click on a report inside "Public Folder" does not give the same toolbar as when you right-click on the report and klick on "Change". Actually, I find this funny... Don't see any intuitive explanation (as from many other BO things) for this...

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can An add A Object to The report at any instance

on the Left hand side U will see the Objects and classes and Measures what u have Selected

On the right hand side u will see object Explore under That u will see the database under

that u will see the Objects   Objects ,classes and measures to existing Report